# ASP.NET validation controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a situation where I have a form that has some validation controls for required fields. They fire just fine if the user does not have the required fields.

The thing is I also have a menu above the form which allows the user to select another location which is then reflected on the form.

This is where I run into an issue...

If the user already selected a location and then wishes to change to a different location, the form does not allow for this as required fields have not been entered.

I was wondering if there is a way to tell the validation controls not to fire in these situation.

My other option would be to do a validation on click of the submit button in which case I would not be able to take advantage of the ASP.NET required validation control.

**Basically I want the validation to occur for the required fields only if the submit button is clicked.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) and [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) properties. I think they will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

On the menu item set CausesValidation to false.

You can also use validation groups and set the validationgroup property of the validator and the submit button to the same value.